# accessing functions declared in some other file using #include in c++

Tags: c++, include

I have a file EnabledSets.cpp in which I am calling a function in following form

```
   ChessImpl::SetEventAttribute(ec.getEventId(sid-1), DISABLE, transition.tid);
```

this I am doing in file named enabledSet.cpp in which I include ChessImpl.h

in chessImpl.h I am including Chess.h which in turn defines the function in Chess.cpp

but when  I am running my code I get this error

```
  EnabledSets.cpp $(.text+0xa0f): undefined reference to `ChessImpl::SetEventAttribute(EventId, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the compiler/linker commandline you're using that gives you this error?

Comment: I suspect you need to forward declare one of your header files. (That would be ChessImpl)

Comment: Your program is not linking to the appropriate library. How you solve that problem depends on your platform, how the library is available to you (dynamic or static), where the library resides on your filesystem and your build mechanism. Provide more detail.

Comment: I am using g++ 4.4 version and defining all of them in same folder

Comment: This is a linker error, not a compiler error. Make sure you link all your object files.

Comment: I am just writing g++ file_name.cpp

Comment: what should be the appropriate linker commanline.. sry I am new to c++ linkers ..

Comment: thanx I have understood whr the mistake was..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't java, you need to pass gcc **ALL** the .cpp files at once, or compile and link separately.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a command like `g++ file_name.cpp` you're telling GCC to compile *and link* that file into a complete program.  It fails because that single file *isn't* a complete program; parts of the program are in other source files.

You can either compile everything at once with:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp -o myprog
```

or you can compile each file individually (into a `.o` file) and then link them as a separate step:

```
g++ -c file1.cpp
g++ -c file2.cpp
g++ file1.o file2.o -o myprog
```

The first way is simpler if you're just typing commands at a prompt, but it's very inefficient when working on a large program since it recompiles everything, even if very little has changed.  Large applications typically have build systems that compile source files individually, and only recompile the ones that have changed.